# pass multiple parameters with <Select> <option>

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Hello as the title suggests, I am trying to pass over multiple parameters with the `option` drop down list and dont know how to do it. I have this code below:

```
echo '<select name="tickets"><option></option>';
    while($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt2)){
    $tName = $row2["tickName"];
    echo "<option value=\"$tickID\">$tName</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
```

How do I also add in tick price? I have tried this:

```
 echo '<select name="tickets"><option></option>';
    while($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt2)){
        $tName = $row2["tickName"];
        $tPrice = $row2["tickPrice"];
        echo "<option value=\"$tickID,$tPrice\">$tName</option>";
    }
echo '</select>';
```

But it wont work, any help is much welcomed. Also while I'm here does anyone have good resources for using SQL Server with the `sqlsrv` api? I can only find the PHP manual site but was wondering if there was perhaps more?

Comment: Thank you Christopher for spell checking it for me :) sadly spelling is not my strong point even more so when this issue has my head killing me lol

Comment: `<select name="tickets[]" multiple>`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027163/how-to-post-two-values-in-an-option-field

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store the ticket prices in the same table as the ticket ids?  Then when you submit the form you can retrieve all the ticket info from the database based on the ticket id.