# Post two values from input field with php

Tags: php, html, forms

I have some registration which sends tag as a value to the server

```
<input type="hidden" id="tag-sm" name="tag-sm" value="workshops_10.2017">
```

Now I must send two different tags

```
<input type="hidden" id="tag-sm" name="tag-sm" value1="workshops_10.2017" value2="events">
```

this is my php:

```
$obj = array(
   'first-name' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['first-name']),
   'last-name' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['last-name']),
   'email' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']),
   'phone' => (isset($_POST['phone'])) ? 
   'tag' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['tag-sm']),
   'discount-codes' => (isset($_POST['discount-codes'])) ? 
);
```

how to get these two values with php ?

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027163/how-to-post-two-values-in-an-option-field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post two values in an option field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027163/how-to-post-two-values-in-an-option-field)

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate `input` for the two

```
<input type="hidden" id="tag-sm-1" name="tag-sm-1" value="workshops_10.2017">
<input type="hidden" id="tag-sm-2" name="tag-sm-2" value="events">
```