# How to sends two Values in select dropdown using php

Tags: php

is it possible to sends two values in

```
 <option value="<?=$halls['id']?>">
```

I want to send like this

```
 <option value="<?=$halls['id']?><?=$halls['rang_from']?>">
```

here is the code.

```
 <?php

    //var_dump($_POST);

    $location=$_POST['location'];
    $hall_query=mysqli_query($connection,"select * from halls where location='$location' and status='enabled'");
    while($halls=mysqli_fetch_assoc($hall_query))
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?=$halls['id']?>"><?=$halls['rang_from']?> To <?=$halls['rang_to']?></option>
    <?php
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Depends on how you want your `select` element to be constructed. I am failing to understand what you are trying to achieve by sending `two` values to the `option` element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post two values in an option field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027163/how-to-post-two-values-in-an-option-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place both values into the value attribute, separated by "/"

```
<option value="<?=$halls['id'] . '/' . $halls['rang_from'] . '/' .  $halls['rang_to']?>"><?= $halls['rang_from']?> To <?=$halls['rang_to']?>
    </option>
```

And When if you want to Recieve It Then Write

```
list($hall_id, $rang_from, $range_to) = explode('/', $_REQUEST['hall']);
```

for  Checking that values comes or Not... Write

```
echo $rang_from; exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

use separator like '|@|'
for example

```
const SEPARATOR = '|@|';
```

in form:

```
<select name="select_name">
    ....
    <option value="<?=$halls['id'] . SEPARATOR . $halls['rang_from']?>"><?=$halls['rang_from']?> To <?=$halls['rang_to']?></option>
    ....
</select>
```

and when receive:

```
list($id, $rang_from) = explode(SEPARATOR, $_REQUEST['select_name']);

echo "id is $id, rang_from is $rang_from";
```

> id is 21, rang_from is home

Comment: ok. thats works. And How to pass 3 Values like `<option value="<?=$halls['id']?><?=$halls['rang_from']?><?=$halls['rang_to']?>">

Comment: <option value="<?=$halls['id'] . SEPARATOR . $halls['rang_from'] . SEPARATOR . $halls['rang_to']?>"><?=$halls['rang_from']?> To <?=$halls['rang_to']?></option>

Comment: list($id, $rang_from, $rang_to) = explode(SEPARATOR, $_REQUEST['select_name']);

Answer (score 0):

you can do by add two values into the one value by `separate` like this in your server side explode the value like this `explode('@@',$value`) by [explode](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp) function

```
<option value="<?=$halls['id'].'@@'.$halls['rang_from']?>">
<?=$halls['rang_from']?> To <?=$halls['rang_to']?></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

passing option value as an JSON array

```
<option 
     value="<?= json_encode(['id' => $halls['id'], 'rang_from' => $halls['rang_from']]) ?>">
     <?=$halls['rang_from']?> To <?=$halls['rang_to']?>
</option>
```

Then use json_decode to fetch the posted array.